# How to bring MainWindow into view when closing a window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bring my MainWindow into view when I close a specific window within the same application. I have tried to do this but with the code I have created it just creates a new instance of MainWindow and I end up having 2 MainWindows instead of a desired one. Here is the code below that I have got.

```
 private void Weight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MultipleConverters.Windows.Weight WeightCalculation = new Windows.Weight();
            WeightCalculation.Show();
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
```

// This code above works fine and minimizes the mainwindow and brings into view the selected window.

```
private void Quit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        MainWindow bringIntoView = new MainWindow();
        bringIntoView.Show();
    }
```

// Now with this code above is the problem code. This code is within the new window and what Iam trying to achieve is when this window is closed the mainwindow will be brought back into scope rather than creating a new instance of it, and leaving me with 2 Mainwindows rather than the desired 1 Mainwindow. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Owner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property to store the reference to the main window, you can then use that property to bring the window back up.

```
private void Weight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MultipleConverters.Windows.Weight WeightCalculation = new Windows.Weight();
        WeightCalculation.Owner = this;
        WeightCalculation.Show();
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

elsewhere

```
private void Quit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Owner.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
```

However based on the behavior you are showing you may want to look in to using [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of minimizing the parent window and use that instead.

```
private void Weight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MultipleConverters.Windows.Weight WeightCalculation = new Windows.Weight();
        WeightCalculation.Owner = this;
        WeightCalculation.ShowDialog(); //The code pauses here till the dialog is closed.
    }
```

Comment: Yeah worked fine ended up using this code although your code gave me the idea lol                        this.Close();
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;               Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy property `Application.Current.MainWindow` that you can use to access the main window declared in App.xaml, you should just be able to show it by calling:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
```

To simplify things, you could create a static method on your MainWindow which handles all this:

```
public static void TryReveal()
{
    var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

    if (mainWindow == null)
    {
        // The main window has probably been closed.
        // This will stop .Show() and .Activate()
        // from throwing an exception if the window is closed.
        return;
    }

    if (mainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }

    // Reveals if hidden
    mainWindow.Show();

    // Brings to foreground
    mainWindow.Activate();
}
```

And then your other windows can just call `MainWindow.TryReveal()`. That way your windows don't need any reference to the main window as the static method handles it.

---

The best way you could handle this in WPF though is (I think) using a messaging implementation (eg. MVVM Light's Messaging system, or Caliburn.Micro's EventAggregator). Your MainWindow would subscribe to a "MainWindowViewStateMessage" or something like that (defined by you) and your other windows would pass it through the messaging system. The main window would intercept it and do the necessary work.

Comment: This will throw an exception because the window has already loaded

Comment: @GlenThomas In my testing this works fine and does not throw an exception.

Comment: Ah yes, it would only throw an exception if the window has been closed, but in the question it has only been minimized

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Quit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        MainWindow bringIntoView = new MainWindow();
        bringIntoView.Show();
    }
```

You're creating a new instance of MainWindow and then showing it. This is why a new MainForm is shown.

One thing you can do is set a property on the WeightCalculation window like this:

```
public MainWindow _mainWindow { get; set; }
```

Before showing the WeightCaculation, set _mainWindow to your current instance of MainWindow :

```
MultipleConverters.Windows.Weight WeightCalculation = new Windows.Weight();
WeightCalculation._mainWindow = this;
WeightCalculation.Show();
this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

and from the new form you can now interact with the MainWindow.

Comment: `Window` already has a perfectly good property for storing this kind of information [`Owner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx), you don't need to make a new property for it.